# jQuery .get('variable url')

Tags: jquery

Am I drowning in a glass of water or is there something tricky about this?

```
$.get('content.html', function (data) {                
            $('#flyout').menu({ content: data, flyOut: true });
        });
```

Thing is content.html will vary amongst users. Sometimes it'll be content.html, some others will be content2.html.

How can I use a variable in the url section of .get? Let's say `var content= '<%=_content%>'` holds the desired value

I have the value stored in a C# variable, and in an asp:Label.

Tried several things but I can't find the way to do it. I've also tried to alert the whole thing but it's giving me the object, changed .et to .ajax and it didn't work either, I must be missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you making an ajax call to a static html page?

Comment: Just... pass the variable: `$.get(content, function....);`

Comment: it's for a menu, html page has a list of /ul/li items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it's already in a variable, use:

```
var content= '<%=_content%>';
$.get(content, function (data) {                
    $('#flyout').menu({ content: data, flyOut: true });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get("<%= _content %>", function (data) {                
    $('#flyout').menu({ content: data, flyOut: true });
});
```